# Unbuffered stdout in python (as in python -u) from within the program

Tags: python

Is there any way to get the effect of running `python -u` from within my code? Failing that, can my program check if it is running in `-u` mode and exit with an error message if not? This is on Linux (Ubuntu 8.10 Server).

Comment: Another workaround is set [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED` env var](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) to any non-empty string.  This is NOT in your code — must be set before python interpreter starts — but is easier than modifying whatever launches your script to add `-u`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This helped me immensely today. I was starting a FastAPI service from a bash file (running uvicorn), which is itself started from a SystemD .service file. I realized that some of my stdout was being buffered and only spilling out when the program terminated, not at the beginning when I wanted to see it. Since the Python startup is a couple of layers deep, I was trying to figure out how to convince uvicorn to add the "-u" when it started Python, but with this method, I was able to simply add a

Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=anystringhere

to the service definition! Nice!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The best I could come up with:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> unbuffered = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
>>> unbuffered.write('test')
test>>> 
>>> sys.stdout = unbuffered
>>> print 'test'
test
```

Tested on GNU/Linux. It seems it should work on Windows too. If I knew how to reopen sys.stdout, it would be much easier:

```
sys.stdout = open('???', 'w', 0)
```

References:
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open
http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#file-object-creation

[Edit]

Note that it would be probably better to close sys.stdout before overwriting it.

Comment: `stdout` still lives in `sys.__stdout__`

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Py3K. `ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O`

Comment: The answers on this question are terribly out of date. Please refer to the linked question for Python 3.3+ answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/2111778

Answer (score 40):

You could always pass the -u parameter in the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
```

Comment: See title: 1. OP knows about it; 2. wants to do it programmatically.

Comment: The author implies command-line usage, not indicating familiarity with the alternate invocation offered by the shell (shebang).  Thanks for your helpful feedback though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the "env trick". `#!/usr/bin/env python -u`.  I get the following error `/usr/bin/env: python -u: No such file or directory`. If I remove the `-u` it works again.

Comment: To follow up my comment a moment ago, I think this explains my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e

Comment: (me again!). Here is a solution to that problem I discussed in my two comments above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458528/why-does-this-snippet-work . (But yes, this isn't related to the original question here)

Comment: This is neat...

Comment: As Aaron says, plainly adding the option to the shebang doesn't work. Instead, pass the `-S` option to the `env` command, like so: `#!/usr/bin/env -S python3 -u`

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're on Windows:

```
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

... and on Unix:

```
fl = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
fl |= os.O_SYNC
fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, fl)
```

(Unix copied in from commented solution, rather than linking.)

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that. on linux (ubuntu)

Comment: @Martin DeMello: Please do not add new facts in comments.  Please update your question with new facts.  New facts in comments are hard to find.

Comment: Supported on unix, linux, and anything posix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering/1736047#1736047

Comment: Note that this does not work with python2 (no error, output is still buffered). Found out when running a script with the wrong interpreter

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT** (Oct 2020). As pointed out in [a note to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881696/unbuffered-stdout-in-python-as-in-python-u-from-within-the-program/882057?noredirect=1#comment113509859_882057), in Python3, stderr *is* buffered too.

You might use the fact that stderr is never buffered and try to redirect stdout to stderr:

```
import sys
#buffered output is here
doStuff()

oldStdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
#unbuffered output from here on

doMoreStuff()
sys.stdout = oldStdout

#the output is buffered again
doEvenMoreStuff()
```

Comment: a hack, but a very cute one :) doesn't really work if you need your stderr separate but nice idea

Comment: thanks. as to the separation: you can't get it all, can you :)

Comment: "stderr is never buffered" - no longer true; in python3, stderr is line buffered if to a tty, fully buffered if to a file or pipe.