# How do I write a unix filter in python?

Tags: python, unix, filter

I want to write a program that reads stdin (unbuffered) and writes stdout (unbuffered) doing some trivial char-by-char transformation. For the sake of the example let's say I want to remove all chars `x` from stdin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by buffered in this context, but it is pretty simple to do what you are asking...

so_gen.py (generating a constant stream that we can watch):

```
import time
import sys
while True:
    for char in 'abcdefx':
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

so_filter.py (doing what you ask):

```
import sys
while True:
    char = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if not char:
        break
    if char != 'x':
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Try running `python so_gen.py | python so_filter.py` to see what it does.

Comment: winner for writing `if not char: break`

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`fileinput` class](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html), which lets you process inputs like the Perl diamond operator would.  From the docs:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

where process does something like `print line.replace('x','')`.

You can follow [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881696/unbuffered-stdout-in-python-as-in-python-u-from-within-the-program) for how to unbuffer stdout.  Or you can just call `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `print`.

Comment: Ah! This makes all the extra work I was doing because I missed Perl for naught! I need to go through the Python standard library very closely.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the `fileinput` module is made exactly for this use case.

Answer (score 15):

Read from `sys.stdin` and write to `sys.stdout` (or use `print`).  Your example program:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.replace("x", ""),
```

There isn't a standard way to make stdin unbuffered, and you don't want that. Let the OS buffer it.

Comment: He did say "unbuffered" but I'm not sure it really matters.

Answer (score 5):

Use the -u switch for the python interpreter to make all reads and writes unbuffered. Similar to setting `$| = true;` in Perl. Then proceed as you would, reading a line modifying it and then printing it. sys.stdout.flush() not required.

```
#!/path/to/python -u

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    process_line(line)
```