# How to read a file (or stdin) line by line in Python not waiting for reading entire file

Tags: python, filter

I want to read and process some large files line by line in python and output results in the terminal. I have gone through [How do I read from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393) and [How do I write a unix filter in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589994), but I am looking for methods which do not wait till the entire file is read into memory.

I would be using both of these commands:

```
cat fileName | python myScript1.py
python myScript2.py fileName
```

Comment: There are three separate issues here: 1) deciding whether to use the command line arguments as filenames or to read from standard input (trivial); 2) opening the file (possibly multiple files) names on the command line and setting them up to be read from; 3) doing line by line reading. The first duplicate addresses the first two points; the second addresses reading line by line (of course). But also, the top answers on the "how do you read from stdin" link all describe line-by-line reading from stdin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the [standard behavior of file objects](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) in Python:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        # do something with the current line
```

or

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # do something with the current line
```

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate over the [file](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects):

```
with open('huge.file') as hf:
  for line in hf:
    if 'important' in line:
      print(line)
```

This will require O(1) memory.

To read from stdin, simply iterate over [`sys.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) instead of `hf`:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  if 'important' in line:
    print(line)
```

Comment: I am a python newbie, can you please explain "simply iterate over sys.stdin instead of hf". Do you mean `for line in sys.stdin` ?

Comment: Yes, `sys.stdin` is just a [file object](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=stdin#sys.stdin) that behaves like a file you have opened manually.

Answer (score -1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        try:
            a=raw_input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        print a
```

This will read from stdin til EOF.
To read a file using the second method, you can use Tim's method

i.e.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        print line
        # do something with the current line
```

Comment: Thanks for both the methods :)

Comment: This method to read from stdin is extremely cumbersome. `sys.stdin` is a file-like object and can be used instead.