# Python's print function that flushes the buffer when it's called?

Tags: python, flush

I have the following code to flushing out the output buffer.

```
print('return 1')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Can I set up the print function so that it automatically flushes the buffer when it's called?

Comment: Hm, goofed up my link, should have been: [unbuffered stdout in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881696/unbuffered-stdout-in-python-as-in-python-u-from-within-the-program)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can start python in unbuffered mode using the -u flag, e.g.

```
python -u script.py
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -u
```

as "shebang" header for your script.