# tracking completion status in loop

Tags: python

In this loop, the output i am expecting is a '.' to be printed after each url in the tuples list gets downloaded . The idea is a sort of progress bar to tell me that the script hasn't crashed or anything. But while running, all the '.'s are getting printed together after all the files have been downloaded. why?

```
for tuple in tuples:
    urllib.urlretrieve(tuple[0],'/media/aux1/pythonary/getxkcd_files/strip'+str(number))
    print'.',
    hypertext='<h2>'+tuple[2]+'  xkcd no.-'+str(number)+'</h2><p><img src="getxkcd_files/strip'+str(number)+'" title="'+tuple[1]+'"/></p>'
    f.write(hypertext)
    number+=1
```

Comment: Same question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895481/pythons-print-function-that-flushes-the-buffer-when-its-called)

Comment: thanks. that totally solves my problem.