# How do I force setup.py to auto-generate a console script with unbuffered output mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, entry-point

In Python 3, it's my understanding that the [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points/782984#782984) to build a Python command line script is to treat it as an "entry point" into a python package, and then use `setup.py` in order to auto-generate the actual script itself, based upon a `main()` function found somewhere within in the package.

I've found some decent tutorials [here](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html), [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/#entry-points) and [here](https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/) which explain exactly how to do that.

The problem with auto-generating the script is that I'm not sure how to control the contents of the "shebang" line (e.g., `#!/usr/bin/env python`) which would typically appear near the top of the script--that part is auto-generated for me.

I would like to design the command line script so that the "shebang" line automatically calls python with certain python flags enabled by default

In particular, I want to run the script as `python -u` in order to turn off stdout buffering as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering).

What would I need to put in my `setup.py` file in order to tell `setuptools` to do that for me?  Of course I could just edit the auto-generated script by hand afterward, but that seems like it would utterly defeat the purpose of having a system to auto-generate console scripts in the first place.  Is there a way to do it, or is this just a fundamental limitation of the "package entry point" model for creating command line scripts?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways this topic is treated on Stack Overflow.
I will list two examples:

- accomplish what you want [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443807/5682996) (which is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/882060/5682996)
- [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17329493/5682996) `sys.executable` / provide 'execute' argument (Remark: I don't know exactly if this works for the `-u` option)