# Python print not working before long task?

Tags: python

I have a script that makes many (hundreds of thousands of) files, and I want to so something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("Generating...", end = "")
doStuff()
print(" Done")
```

Because of the `end = ""`, I'd expect `Generating...` to show up before the long task, and for it to change to `Generating... Done` when it's finished. However, the first `print()` doesn't show up until after `doStuff()` has completed, immediately before the second `print()`. a `time.sleep(1)` before `doStuff()` doesn't do anything, although it wouldn't be a permanent solution anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush `sys.stdout` periodically for the characters to show up:

```
import sys

print 'Working',

while working():
    work()

    print '.',

    sys.stdout.flush()

print 'Done'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I just added `sys.stdout.flush()` before `doStuff()`. Seems like Python is the type of language not to have this kind of a problem, but works perfectly nonetheless.

Comment: @tkbx: It might depend on your platform (and terminal emulator?). I have to do this under Linux, but Windows doesn't seem to have this issue.

Comment: I'm on Mac using the default emulator in bash, havent tested any other OSes yet (but I'll be using this on Linux primarily)

Comment: Reopening stdout unbuffered `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)` should save you repeated flushing.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your interpreter that buffers the output. Running "python -u yourfile.py" should fix that.

Comment: I'm running it as an executable (./script), and it's not really a permanent solution...

Comment: OK, I thought your shell would invoke a python interpreter to interpret your script (maybe indicated by a shebang), this at least does mine. For general unbuffered output cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881696/unbuffered-stdout-in-python-as-in-python-u-from-within-the-program et al.

Comment: It does, but I can't `python -u` this way.