# time module sequence in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import time

def threedot():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print '.',
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print '.',
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print '.'

threedot()
```

When the above code is run, the interpreter waits 1.5 seconds and then prints '. . .'; rather than wait 0.5 seconds in-between printing '.'. Why is this?
(on python 2.7.3)

Comment: You may also consider this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881696/unbuffered-stdout-in-python-as-in-python-u-from-within-the-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is being cached until one of several events which your code doesn't actually trigger until the final `print`. Flush the output (hint: `sys.stdout.flush()`) each time.

Comment: <pedantic>libc is buffering the output,  not the OS.</pedantic>

Answer (score 0):

stdout is usually "line-buffered", meaning libc will buffer the output (and not write it to the console) until a newline is encountered, or the stream is closed.

Either write to stderr, or manually flush the output stream each time.

Comment: This clarifies the problem I had. Thanks.