# Dynamic one-line output in Django management command

Tags: python, django, printing

I have a Django management command that does quite a bit of processing, so I have it outputting its progress as a percentage. I'd like to use a technique as described in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/python-remove-and-replace-printed-items) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically). I'm aware [from the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) that `sys.stdout` needs to be replaced with `self.stdout` when used inside a management command, but I'm still having no luck. It's python 2.7, so I can't give the `end` kwarg to `print`. Here's one of the things I've tried in `handle` of the Command object:

```
i = 0
for thing in query:
    self.stdout.write("\r%%%s" % (100 * float(i) / float(query.count()))
    i += 1
```

I've tried several other techniques described in answers to similar questions, including using [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Is there something special about the way that Django management commands print output? How can I achieve the effect I'm looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## tl;dr

stdout output is buffered by default, so flush manually:

```
import time

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "My shiny new management command."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("Writing progress test!")
        for i in range(100):
            self.stdout.write("%{}".format(i), ending='\r')
            self.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.01)
```

## Reference

I followed [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19593) that someone opened a few years back, and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881696/unbuffered-stdout-in-python-as-in-python-u-from-within-the-program); see both for longer details and other solutions, such as the [python -u option](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).

Comment: Thanks for this! i had been doing `write` with `ending='\r'` without `flush()` and pulling my hair out!